# KafkaSpout Read partition information from: .../partition_0 --> null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have an existing storm topology which uses `KafkaSpout` (which is not written by me). When it starts it try to read Kafka topics state from `/kafkaroot/topicname/partition_0`. When I create Kafka topic with `kafka-topics.sh` it add it to `/brokers/topics/topicname/partition/0`. What should I change? 
I have an error UnresolvedAddressException, which I think related to this.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:103) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:135) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3284$fn__3299$fn__3328.invoke(executor.clj:563) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:431) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:644) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(BlockingChannel.scala:57) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.connect(SimpleConsumer.scala:44) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOrMakeConnection(SimpleConsumer.scala:142) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:69) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:124) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:77) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:67) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:83) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What do want to achieve? Changing the read location of KafkaSpout or changing the location in which the new topic is generated?

Comment: I want  to resolve current error java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
 at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:103). May be /kafkaroot/topicname/partition_0 must be written by storm  itself?

Comment: Can you please add the exception to you question (with proper formatting). Furthermore, I still don't know what you want to change... The configuration of KafkaSpout ot kafka-topics.sh.

Comment: i do not understand is it normal that i have two different paths and if it is then why do  i have that error

Comment: Can you also add your `SpoutConfig`.

Comment: SpoutConfig(brokerhost, "kafkatopic", "kafkaroot", "kafkatopic");

Comment: Can you also provide your full "kafka-topics.sh ..." command. (Please update your question; also with the SpoutConfig -- it is easier to have all information in one place and not scattered around the comments)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your server which runs KafkaSpout cannot resolves brokerhost hostname. 
Can you ping your brokerhost from a server which runs storm topology? Or try command

telnet brokerHosts brokerPort

Comment: yes   i can't connect to zk ip on port 2181 with telnet. but it can be  connected with zkCLi -server.

Comment: I think you dont have problem with resolving zookeper hostname, but with resolving kafka broker hostname.
When you check zookeper data from zkCli:  get /kafka/brokers/ids/0
You can find broker hostname and port.

Comment: result of zkCli get {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1440964800233","host":"user-VirtualBox","version"
:1,"port":9092}
cZxid = 0x11e
ctime = Sun Aug 30 23:00:00 MSK 2015
mZxid = 0x11e
mtime = Sun Aug 30 23:00:00 MSK 2015
pZxid = 0x11e
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x14f70beec610051
dataLength = 95
numChildren = 0

Comment: Can you connect from every machine which runs storm topology?

telnet user-VirtualBox 9092

Comment: i have only one machine, ubuntu on Virtualbox.